# Передача данных с класса в класс php

Tags: php, ооп, классы

Есть два класса hello и world

```
class hello {

    public $data;

    public function setup() {

        $this->data = 'lorem ipsum';

        $world = new world;
        $world->data = $this->data

    }

}

class world {

    public $data;

    public function setup() {

        echo $this->data;

    }

}
```

Создал экземпляр класса и присвоил данные с переменной в переменную но результат null

Функцию я вызываю в отдельном фале, но данные не передаются в класс world

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: а как вы получаете сей результат? `$world->setup()` в данном коде вы не вызываете.  это полный код?

Comment: Нет функцию я вызываю в отдельном фале.

Comment: В класс-то данные передаются. Но вот что с ним дальше происходит. не надо думать что классы существуют во всепроникающем эфире и живут вечно. В РНР есть такая вещь, как **область видимости**

Comment: у вас область видимости переменной `$world` ограничена методом `hello::setup`, вы ее в принципе нигде не можете вызвать кроме данного метода.

Comment: Как же тогда передать данные?

Comment: @verstala [см. демо](https://ideone.com/cq2CB6)

Answer (score 0):

Данные передаются. Просто вы с ними ничего не делаете. В вашем коде не хватает вызова метода дочернего объекта.

```php
    class hello {
    
        public $data;
    
        public function setup() {
    
            $this->data = 'lorem ipsum';
    
            $world = new world;
            $world->data = $this->data

            $world->setup();    
        }    
    }
```

После выхода из метода `hello::setup` объект `$world` перестает существовать, поскольку он находится в области видимости только этой функции.
Чтобы можно было к этому объекту обратиться позже, попробуйте

1. либо вернуть объект через `return $world;` в методе `hello::setup` и потом дернуть уже его метод setup()

   ```php
   $hello = new hello()
   $world = $hello->setup()
   $world->setup()
   // или же все это одной строкой:
   (new hello())->setup()->setup()
   ```
2. либо положить его в какое-нибудь свойство класса `hello`. Например, так:

   ```php
   class hello {

       public $data;

       private $world;

       public function setup() {

           $this->data = 'lorem ipsum';

           $this->world = new world;
           $this->world->data = $this->data    
       }

       public function getWorld() {
           return $this->world;
       }
   }

   $hello = new hello();
   $hello->setup();
   $world = $hello->getWorld()
   $world->setup();
   ```

P.S. Огромная просьба! Следуйте рекомендациям [PSR-1](https://svyatoslav.biz/misc/psr_translation/#_PSR-1), именуйте классы в StudlyCaps! В вашем примере это будут имена `Hello` и `World`.